# Appending on a copied python list

Tags: python, list

Why does instantly appending on a copied python list not work?

I have the following code:

```
mylist = [1]
mylist2 = mylist.copy()
mylist2.append(2)
```

This gives me the expected mylist2 = [1,2].
Why does the following code lead to a None?

```
mylist = [1]
mylist2 = mylist.copy().append(2)
```

Comment: Because `append()` doesn't return a value. So technically, it does create a copy, and append a value, but you're just not "catching" it.

Comment: Ok that does make sense. @MechanicPig The explanation of the design decision in this answer was also really helpful.